# Image Composition Services for Ecommerce

Tags: ecommerce, magento, image-hosting

I'm researching the market for image composition services for ecommerce software.  Systems that will manage high resolution images for product variations (multiple colors, different text/logo on the same image of a lady, etc.)

Specific questions.

- Scene7 seems to be the leader in this space. Are there lower cost alternatives to Scene7?
- What sort of costs **can** I expect for this kind of hosted service? Scene7 doesn't list prices, which leads me to believe they have metrics to size up each client and maximize profits.
- Outside of the software as a service market, are their open-source and/or commercial self hosted solutions?
- Not necessary, but any services with out of the box Magento integration jump to the front of the line.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick is free - I have used it to stamp 'preview' on pictures before, make dynamic fancy text out of people's names (it was wrapped around an orange in cloves, before you ask why I didn't just use @font-face) amongst other things.

You install ImageMagick yourself and integrate it with your own service. A lot of platforms and CMSs provide plugins for it.

Comment: +1 ImageMagick is great, but it's a **very raw** tool. I'm looking for more fully (or even half) formed solutions.

Comment: OK, the only other one I know in that space is [Fluid](http://www.fluid.com). I haven't much exposure to either, apart from being seeing the demos on trade stands.